# addTarget:action:forControlEvents: can you pass a dictionary or anything

Tags: iphone

I have a custom cell for a UITableView. The cell has a button in it called ShowData.  I add a selector for that button:

```
[cell.ShowData addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventsTouchUpInside];
```

in My ShowData: method, I'd like some of the info that I used in displaying the cell.  How can I pass information in this way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `showData:` will receive the button itself as its `sender` argument.  You can walk up the button's superviews until you find your custom cell and then access any properties you've added to the cell.

```
- (IBAction)showData:(id)sender
{
    while (sender && ![sender isKindOfClass:[MyCustomTableViewCell class]])
        sender = [sender superview];
    if (!sender) {
        // error
    }

    MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = sender;
    // do stuff using cell
}
```

Comment: is sucks to find that this is the only way to pass extra data on a selector like this.  this surely doesn't seem like a best practice.  is this really how everyone does this?

Comment: @rob mayoff How do I do that in code?  Right now I just get my [button superview], and then I find out it's of type UITableViewCellContentView which I have not seen before.  I tried to call superview on that but I get an error of undeclared identifier UITableViewCellContentView.  I'm not sure what a good loop to automate this would be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I usually subclass the button and add an ivar to identify it with the UITableViewCell.

For example, you could have two NSInteger properties, buttonIndex and buttonSection to identify the section and row of the tableview that your button is in.

When you construct your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you could assign indexPath.row to buttonIndex and indexPath.section to buttonSection.

Now, in your showData method, just read in the sender as your custom button, and access those properties :)

EDIT:

You could just as simply set button.tag = indexPath.row if you're using a single section tableview. UIButton inherits from UIView which has a tag property meant specifically for that purpose.